# AWS CloudWatch Logs Data limitation

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there any data limitation on aws cloudwatch logs to send the logs , because in my case I am getting the logs data 6 million records per 3 days from my application. So is aws cloudwatch logs will able to handle that much data?

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lac* that are not understood globally -- as you can see from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [aws quotas page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html). Not sure what you mean by "60lac" but the limits on CloudWatch are more than adequate for the majority of use cases.

There is no published limit on the overall data volume held. There'll be a practical limit somewhere but it won't be hit by a single AWS customer. If you're using the putLogEvents API you could be constrained by the limit of 5 requests per second per log stream, in which case consider using more streams or larger batches of events (up to 1MB).

Comment: "Lac" is Indian word for 100 000, so that's 6 million.

Comment: @Ed Eastwood   Yes there is 6million records in 3days so will aws cloudwatch logs able to handle that much logevent records?

Comment: @RahulChauhan I wouldn't see that as a problem. If they are evenly distributed (and that's a big assumption - if your workload spikes the concurrent demand could be much higher) that works out at just over 23 log events per second. You could spread that over five streams and be within the API limit. I've seen tests running at over 200K events over five minutes and that's not a limit, that's just what the use case required.